# How to design an iterable but immutable (read-only) collection

Tags: java, design, data-structures

My program models a sport tournament which has one or many events or categories. The class `Event` has members like players or courts as a `List`, as well as some dictionaries using the class `Map`.

So far accessing publicly those members can be done through their respective getters, but I realized this is a bad practice because it allows modifications through the collection object retrieved with the getter. And I wouldn't want this.

I would like to limit the set of operations allowed on these members and avoid the situation described above.

One might think just declaring these members as `final` would do, but it doesn't. These members can still be modified, just instead of freely doing that directly with the native `List` or `Map` methods, it's done via my classes' methods.

So let's say I clamp the collections set of operations allowed on these collections and I make wrapping classes for my lists and maps, so instead of having this:

```
private List<Player> players;
private List<Court> courts;

private Map<Player, List<Timeslot>> playersUnavailable;
```

I could have something like:

```
private CustomList<Player> players;
private CustomList<Court> courts;

private CustomMap<Player, List<Timeslot>> playersUnavailable;
```

The name of the classes would probably need to be different, I just can't think of something better at the moment.

Say we just want reader methods for these classes. So we could have a method to get the size and another to get a particular element of the internal collection:

```
public class CustomList<T> {
    private final List<T> list;
    public CustomList<T>(List<T> l) { list = l; }
    public int size() { return list.size(); }
    public int get(int i) { return list.get(i); }
}
```

However, now I can't iterate through items of a collection like I normally would:

```
for (Player player : players)
    System.out.println(player);
```

Although I could use `get()` and `size()` but it feels a bit rudimentary.

What could I do to make these collections iterable but preserving the immutability rules my design has? (As I said it's not strictly immutability, since you can do it using the pertinent methods)

Overall, should I rethink my design differently? Does what I'm trying to do make sense? Could I achieve it differently, in a better way?

I guess I could say what I am looking for are read-only collections, am I?

Comment: Are you looking for the `List<T>` to be read only or every item in `List<T>`, or both?

Comment: Just the list itself. The items are fine. Although my class includes a map of maps, so getting that map would be tricky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you have two requirements here:

1. `Event` exposes collections, but callers cannot modify those collections.
2. `Event` can modify its collections, but only through the `Event` class.

It sounds like you need to use immutable [collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), for example, [java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(List list)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-). However, you do not want to store an immutable collection as the state in `Event`. It could work like this:

```
public class Event {

  private List<Player> players;

  public List<Player> getPlayers() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(players);
  }

  public void addPlayer(Player p) {
    players.add(p);
  }
}
```

This allows modifying the collections through `Event`, while still allowing callers to get an immutable reference suitable for iteration. The call to `Collections.unmodifiableList(players)` wraps the list `players` and does *not* copy it.

If this needs to be thread-safe then there are additional concerns to address here, but that was not a requirement. It sounds more like your `Event` class needs to handle invariants and data integrity between multiple collections that model the same objects. That concern should easily be addressable using this technique.

Comment: [Writing immutable collections correctly is hard.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/171298/1204) (see the comments below my answer)

Comment: I would definitely not provide mutating operations on the wrapper if immutability is desired. But then you essentially have whatever nested class the `Collections` class returns for its `immutableXYZ()` methods anyway.

Comment: This leads to the same problem I mentioned about using the `final` modifier. I said **I do want to be able to modify the internal collections**, just **not** with the native collections' methods, but with the pertinent method defined in the class itself.

Comment: @dabadaba from your question: "I guess I could say what I am looking for are read-only collections, am I?" based on your comment on my answer, I think your question is unclear. Perhaps it would help if you edit your question to resolve this ambiguity? I read the question as you wanted immutable collections.

Comment: @dabadaba I think I get it now, please see the edit to my answer. I would like to reiterate that **this is not thread-safe** which is often a reason for desiring immutability. If you just want to ensure data integrity in a single-threaded situation this will work. If it must be thread-safe, that is a whole different issue and will greatly complicate your design.

Comment: @Snowman I am not concerned about thread safety. This will be for single-threaded purposes. However, doing  it the way you suggested, now I will get a **copy** of the list, right? That's undesirable because I do a lot of comparisons and checks for containment (in the sense that the list contains an object) and now the references would change. If the question is unclear though, I might just create a new question trying to explain myself properly, and adding some more examples.

Comment: No, `Collections` provides _wrappers_ for collections, those `unmodifiableXYZ()` methods do _not_ copy anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices, other than rolling your own -- slap a facade over a modifiable list (like `UnmodifiableList`) that doesn't allow modification *through that interface*, or use one of the available third party libraries that is truly immutable. The problem with the facade approach is that someone (say, a subclass) could modify the underlying list, breaking the contract implied by presenting an `UnmodifiableList`.  An example of the latter is Guava's [ImmutableList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) which is truly immutable, inherently making a defensive copy when initialized from a List.